# Java: most efficient string manipulation -> getting the "1" out of "1-9"

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to get the "1" out of "1-9" or the "125" out of "125-749" with Java, how would I do that most easiest?

Comment: Easiest or most efficient? There's a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest is probably to use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
str.split("-")[0]
```

where `str` is your string in question.

If you want the fastest, the following can do ~200 million iterations per second on my box:

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf('-'))
```

(In both cases, error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 0):

Use  String.split()

```
 str.split("-")[0]
```